# All items dialling the same number in ListView

Tags: java, android

I have successfully allowed my application to dial a number (in this case 123), when clicking on a `ListView` item. However, I have three `ListView` items and I want them all do dial separate numbers.  For example:

Item 1: 123

Item 2: 321

Item 3: 231

At present, they all dial number 123.

Any help on differentiating between `ListItems` would be appreciated.

```
ListView simpleList;
        String contactList[] = {"X", "Y", "Z"};

        simpleList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.contact_list);
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_contact_list_view, R.id.textView, contactList);
        simpleList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

simpleList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String value = (String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:123"));

                startActivity(callIntent);

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Well it looks as though you are passing along the value to your intent hardcoded as  `callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:123"));` This would of course provide the same telephone number every time.   After the built-in activity launches from this intent, it will extract the data through a similar manner that we would as a programmer.

```
String telephoneNumber = getIntent().getExtraString("Telephony")
```

That string that the activity intent receives is what you assign inside `callIntent.setData()`.  So in order to provide an appropriate telephone number to your dialer, you will need to set the appropriate string there.  I am not sure how you have the contactList setup with respect to the phone numbers.  But all you must do once you know which contact you have is get their phone number and assign it here:

```
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + telephoneNumber));
```

Comment: Thanks, @Bronze. I'm not sure what you mean though. Would you mind re-wording so I can understand a bit better?

Comment: @FaceValue Let me know if you have a further question in regards to that, but I have updated the response above.

Comment: Just to be clear, do I need to assign a phone number to each of the three items in the `ListView`. Sorry I'm a bit confused, quite new at all this.